# Adding a handler to popup leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Suppose we have a project using leaflet.js. When clicking on the map i want a popup to appear that gives me a dropdown menu with a submit button. The dropdown function has 3 options a,b,c. I want to be able to create a submit button that creates a marker at the location (LatLong) of the popup. this marker must show the string of the choice made in the dropdown menu.

First of all i tried option 1 in the code, however a i get a reference error whenever i create a handler. I also tried the option 2 where one creates a div object. I tried creating the div object manually as well with ID "popupcontent" which worked, however the handler does not remember the lat-long cooridnates.

In summary:

I want to create a button that makes a marker at the place clicked with the content of either a,b,c depending on the choice in the dropdown menu.

option 1

```
var dropdown =
    `Type to submit:
    <select>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value = "c">c</option>
    </select>: <button onclick="buttonFunction()">submit</button>`

  var popup = L.popup();
  function onMapClick(e) {
    popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent(dropdown)
    .openOn(mymap);
    //L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(mymap);
    //L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.long]).addTo(mymap)
  }
```

option2

```
var popup = L.popup();
  var container = L.DomUtil.create('div');
  var btn = L.DomUtil.create('button', '', container);
  btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
  btn.innerHTML = 'hello kees';
  L.DomEvent.on(btn, 'click', () => {
    alert("hello kees");
  });
  function onMapClick(e) {
    popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent(container)
    .openOn(mymap);
    //L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(mymap);
    //L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.long]).addTo(mymap)
  }
```

GOAL:

```
function onMapClick(e) {
    popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent( "LatLong: "+ e.latlng.lat + "," + e.latlng.lng)
    .openOn(mymap);
    lat = e.latlng.lat
    long = e.latlng.lng
  }

function buttonFunction() {
  var selected = document.getElementById("popupContent");
  var value = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].text;
  L.marker(lat,long).addTo(mymap);
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve when you call  `buttonFunction`? Add another marker? I didn't understand. Can you rephrase your description to be more clear?

Comment: i edited what i want :D

Comment: Ok. So you want to click on a map, create a popup at the position you clicked with the mouse and then call `buttonFunction` and create a marker in the position of the popup therefore under the popup. correct?

Comment: yes :D. I manually created a div object outside the onMapClick function but this only worked in specific situations.

Comment: Is [that](https://jsfiddle.net/rs52zfuk/) what you want to achieve? If that is the case I will post it as an answer cause still it is quite strange to add a popup first and then a marker...

Comment: almost, i want to see per marker what value has been assigned to it when i hover over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create your const which will hold the html and assign an `id` to the `select` element to be able to get the value later.

Second, create the map `onclick` function get the `latLng` and create on the fly the `popup`.

Third step, get the value from the drop down list and create the marker dynamically by assigning as its popup select's value.

Open the example in full page to reproduce it.

```css
#map {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="map">
</div>

<script>
  let latLng;
  const map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(map);

  const dropdown =
    `Type to submit:
    <select id="ddlViewBy">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value = "c">c</option>
    </select>: <button onclick="buttonFunction()">submit</button>`;

  map.on('click', e => {
    const popup = L.popup()
      .setLatLng(e.latlng)
      .setContent(dropdown)
      .openOn(map);
    latLng = e.latlng;
  })

  buttonFunction = () => {
    const dropdonwValue = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy").value;
    map.closePopup()
    L.marker(latLng)
      .bindPopup(dropdonwValue)
      .addTo(map)
  }

</script>
```